# How can excel highlight matching entries between 2 tables/4 columns

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find the duplicates between Table 1 and Table 2. The entires in  column 'A' and 'B'together has to match the entries in column 'C' and 'D'

Looking for a formula that will highlight the duplicates in the given scenario.

![Table 1 has 2 columns, A and B. Table 2 has two columns, B and C. The formula should highlight the text in A and B together to text in B and C together][using excel]

Comment: Your description is confusing. A and B, then C and D, Then A and B with B and C. Are the two tables in one sheet? That does not make sense. Please post a data sample with "Before" and "After" and describe the logic. Use a file sharing service and post a link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create "key" columns to make things easier: Column X  = A & B, Column Y = C & D

Then you can either use vlookup(A&B,Y...) or vlookup(C&D,X...)

Or Match(A&B, Y...( etc will give you the row number which could be useful, plus is a lot quicker than vlookup if you have heaps of rows (plus you don't need to lookup anything so why not? Or even if you did Index(Match..)) is still quicker...

Or you could even use Countif(A&B, Y) and vice versa...

Thats a hell of a lot of pseudo formulas lol so maybe something like:

`Sheet2.D1 Formula: "=CountIf(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$1000, A1 & B1)"` and do the same on the other:

`Sheet1.D1 Formula: "=CountIf(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$1000, A1 & B1)"`

```
Sheet1!C1 Formula = "=A1 & B1"
Sheet2!C1 Formula = "=A1 & B1"
```

Or if you only have one duplicate and want to know the row number:

Sheet1.D1 Formula: `"=If(isna(match(A1 & B1,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$1000,0)),"","Duplicate on row: " & match(A1 & B1,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$1000,0))"`